# how do I answer/caluculate this statistical problem

Tags: statistics

The average (arithmetic mean) of 100 measurements is 23 and the average of 50 additional is 27.  What is the average of the 150 measurements?

Comment: Can you use the information to find the **sum** of the $150$ measurements? (This is the crude way, we can be a little fancier.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: What is the sum of the first $100$? What is the sum of the additional $50$? What now?

**Alternate Hint**: We can pretend that the first $50$ measurements and the next $50$ measurements both had an average of $23.$ What is the average of $23,23,$ and $27$? This approach is less straightforward, and requires justification, but it still works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can assume (think why) that all the initial $100$ measurements are equal to $23$ each and all the subsequent $50$ measurements are equal to $27$ each. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

**[(23*100)+(27*50)]/150=24.3333333333**

**[(23*50)+(23*50)+(27*50)]/150=24.3333333333**

Think of it as there being 100 23's and 50 27's because it doesn't matter what the actually numbers are because they will each make up for each other in a way such that it is equivalent to every number in the set being that number.

Another example: **[(26*50)+(20*50)+(30*25)+(24*25)]/150=24.3333333333**

Here you see (23*100)/100 is equal to [(26*50)+(20*50)]/100

Because 26 is three more than 23 and 20 is three less

26*50 gives you an over count of 150 and 20*50 gives you an under count of 150 they cancel out